# 5 photons detected from a star in 1 hour. What is probability that 3 photons will be detected in the next hour?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, bayesian

This is a question I was working on from Phil Gregory's Bayesian Logical Data Analysis and I ended up getting stuck here.

The question seems like a simple Poisson rate-problem by taking $rate = 5/hour$ and then easily from that you can calculate $p(n=3|r,t)$ however the next question then specifies ***on average*** 5 photons are detected per hour which made me doubt my method for this question.

I then assumed that we didn't know the rate exactly and so this is my new attempt using Bayesian methods however it seems very long and I'm worried I've over-complicated it and actually the answer is very simple - please help!

$$ n_1 = 5 ; n_2 = 3 ; t_1 = t_2 = t = 1$$
$$ I = prior $$
$$p(n_2|n_1,I) = \int p(n_2|n_1,I,r) p(r|n_1,I) dr\tag{1}$$ where I am trying to marginalise over $r$.

$$p(r|n_1,I) = \frac{p(r|I)p(n_1|r,I)}{p(n_1|I)}\tag{2}$$ (Bayes' theorem)
and so 
$$p(n_1|I) = \int^{1000}_0 p(r|I) p(n_1|r,I) dr \tag{3}$$
where I'm assuming a Jeffrey's prior for $r$ between 0 and 1000, so that $p(r|I) = \frac{k}{r}$ where $k$ is a constant. As it's a Poisson process, $p(n_1|r,I) = e^{-rt} \frac{rt^{n_1}}{n_1!} $

Doing this integral and subbing it back into eqn (2) produces (where I've set all t = 1)
$$p(r|n_1,I) = e^{-r} \frac{r^{n_1-1}}{0.2 * n_1!}\tag{4}$$

Subbing this back into eqn (1) then gives
$$p(n_2|n_1,I) = \int^{1000}_0 e^{-2r} \frac{r^{n_2+n_1-1}}{0.2 *n_2! *n_1!}dr $$
$$ \approx 0.137$$

This value seems a little low and so am I going about it in the right way or am I completely barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Note that the result for the "$5$ on average" case is about $0.140$. I suspect that if you replace $1000$ by $\infty$ that would also be the result here. Perhaps the point of the exercise is to show that the Jeffreys prior (no apostrophe there, by the way, the person's name was Jeffreys) yields the same result as a known rate?